# Data Insertion in Cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to insert data in the cassandra db and it always gets inserted in asc order. I know, I can change it to desc order, but for some rows, I want asc and for some rows i want desc.

Is it possible ?

For example,

```
I have a table : Table1
Column : data

it is map<text,text>

I want to insert data in the following way.

"abc","xyz"
"xz","ab"
```

I found that either we can insert it in asc order or desc. But with each insert, can i tell the order ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to arbitrarily order rows within a table in the storage engine. You choose the sort order when you define the table.

I'm not sure what your schema is, but if we're talking about clustering columns, it is possible to specify the order on `SELECT`: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/doc/cql3/CQL.textile#order-by